# How to rank a matrix based on the score of each row?

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to rank the rows of the matrix based on the score of each row, and this score is calculated using mutual information.

The matrix has 14 rows with different values but when I try to print it with scores in this line

```java
System.out.println(array + " " + score);
```

It shows only the first row repeated 14 times while the score is correct ( it is calculated for the different rows of the matrix).

This is the code

```java
MutualInformation mutuObject = null;

System.out.println("calculateMutualInformation "); 

double[]  fX = new double[numberofrows]; 
int rows = 0, cols = 0;

List<Double> array = new ArrayList<Double>();

for(int r = 0; r < numberoffeatures-1; r++) {
    rows = rowlist.get(r);
    cols = collist.get(r);  

    for(int c = 0; c < numberofrows; c++) {
        int valf= datasetMat[c][r];

        fX[c] = valf;

        // System.out.print(fX3[c] + " ");

        array.add(fX[c]);
    }

    double score = mutuObject.calculateMutualInformation(fX3, colclassVec); 

    System.out.println(array + " " + score);
}

System.out.println("the array" + array);

Collections.sort(array,Collections.reverseOrder());

System.out.println("Sorted List : " + array);

array = array.subList(0, 10);

System.out.println("ranked List : " + array);
```

thanks all

Comment: any help. please!!

Comment: In all honesty, your code is a little hard to debug because of the missing pieces and some of the incoherent identifiers you used. Can you fix these problems and perhaps add some comments?